# How does this electrical ballast need to be wired to the flyback transformer?

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, high-frequency, fluorescent-lamp

I just got myself a flyback transformer and an [electrical ballast](https://www.osram.de/ecat/QUICKTRONIC%20FIT%208-EVG%20f%C3%BCr%20LL%20und%20KLL,%20nicht%20dimmbar-EVG%20f%C3%BCr%20Leuchtstoff-%20und%20Kompaktleuchtstofflampen-Elektronische%20Betriebsger%C3%A4te%20f%C3%BCr%20Lampen-Digital%20Systems/de/de/GPS01_1028000/PP_EUROPE_DE_eCat/ZMP_1014371/) for fluorescent lamps as I heard those can be used together.

The electrical ballast is supposed to generate a high frequency which is exactly what a flyback needs to generate high voltage arcs.

I identified the primary coil of the transformer (it has a 1.8Ohm resistance, the other coils have a resistance of 0.8Ohm and lower) and connected everything but it didn't work. I didn't get sparks from any of the pins to the high voltage cable.

I am assuming that I'm not using the ballast correctly so I will include several pictures for you.

[image: assembled ballast]
assembled ballast

[image: left connector (to the mains i guess)]
left connector (to the mains, I guess)

[image: right connector (to the lamp/tranaformer i guess)]
right connector (to the lamp/transformer, I guess)

[image: top of the circuit board]
top of the circuit board

[image: bottom of the circuit board]
bottom of the circuit board

I hope one of you knows the answer to my problem.

Comment: your problem is here ... `i heard those can be used together`

Comment: [Apparently, it can be done.](https://hackaday.com/2014/02/14/an-easy-way-to-power-flyback-transformers/)  I'd advise you to be very careful - that kind of thing can produce enough power at high voltage to kill you.